# Do desulfhydrase-catalysed reactions take place in animal cells?

Tags: biochemistry

It isn't a homework question. I'm just stuck with desulfhydrase reactions and am unable to find enough information in the usual places.
Any external source on this topic would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A desulfhydrase catalyzes the removal of hydrogen sulfide from a compound. So the answer is **yes, but it's not the most-commonly annotated reaction for the enzyme cystathionine gamma-lyase.**

I didn't know off-hand. Here's how I answered the question:

I searched [Entrez Protein](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/) (or NCBI...whatever the thing's called) with the following terms:

```
(desulfhydrase) AND "Homo sapiens"[porgn:__txid9606]
```

And got three hits for isoforms of cystathionine gamma-lyase. I clicked on one of them and started reading. Key things I noted:

> EC_number="4.4.1.1"
>
> ...
>
> Cystathionine gamma-synthase is a PLP dependent enzyme and catalyzes
>   the committed step of methionine biosynthesis. **This pathway is
>   unique to microorganisms and plants, rendering the enzyme an
>   attractive target for the development of antimicrobials and
>   herbicides.**

So it's a good question because, if people normally characterize this enzyme in terms of Met biosynthesis, then we don't have a desulfhydrase. But I trusted the thing was annotated properly and that the comment above was just too medicine-oriented (as much biochemical literature is).

So to really understand the enzyme itself I searched [MetaCyc](http://www.biocyc.org/META/NEW-IMAGE?type=REACTION&object=RXN-15130c) for the Enzyme Commission identifier 4.4.1.1.

This let's me easily visualize the catalyzed reaction. And the annotation spells it out clearly:

> Enzyme Commission Summary: A *multifunctional* pyridoxal-phosphate
>   protein. The enzyme cleaves a carbon-sulfur bond, releasing L-cysteine
>   and an unstable enamine product that tautomerizes to an imine form,
>   which undergoes a hydrolytic deamination to form 2-oxobutanoate and
>   ammonia. The latter reaction, which can occur spontaneously, can also
>   be catalysed by EC 3.5.99.10, 2-iminobutanoate/2-iminopropanoate
>   deaminase.
>
> **Also catalyses elimination reactions** of L-homoserine to 2-oxobutanoate and ammonia, of L-cystine, producing thiocysteine,
>   pyruvate and ammonia, and **of L-cysteine, producing pyruvate,
>   hydrogen sulfide and ammonia.**

Comment: I removed my comment, my mistake on the EC number.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the reaction described in Ryan's answer, cystathionine beta-synthase (CBS) also [catalyses a reaction](http://humancyc.org/HUMAN/NEW-IMAGE?type=REACTION&object=RXN66-562) that yields hydrogen sulfide. These two reactions are thought to be the [major sources](http://www.jbc.org/content/284/33/22457.long) of hydrogen sulfide in mammals.